# What is the spring equivalent for @ManagedBean?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Is there any annotation for Spring that allows me to use the controller component just like a JSF `@ManagedBean` or CDI `@Named` through EL without having to declare the controller, the form and avoiding all the dirty old Spring config in the JSP page?

Comment: No not with JSP... You would have to switch to JSF (and then read the JSF integration chapter).

Comment: M. Deinum, as much as I know jsf can stand in a .jsp page.

Comment: You can but you shouldn't try to mix (facelets is the preferred way). But basically any `@Component` is accesible from any page. (If you have configured the JSF integration correctly).

Comment: Yes, Deium, I also would like to have a clean field in which to work, but the project in which I work is a 13 year old one and I have some constrictions.
So, changes as little as possible on what already exists (without any test!) and good luck!
Thank you for your answer!

Comment: If you have JSP pages then why not simply stick with JSP... Are they currently JSPs with JSF as a backing technology?